# Are there known instances of a zirconium crown resonating at certain frequencies and causing discomfort?

Tags: dentistry

I've seen a case where a zirconium crown installed on the second molar of a patient vibrates at certain frequencies of vocalization (e.g., nasal consonants, humming higher-frequency notes, i.e., in the second octave of the solfège naming convention: Fa–Sol-La-Si) the crown resonates and makes a buzzing sound (loud to patient but nearly imperceptible outside of the mouth).

Is this a known phenomenon? Do you know of any other examples where this has occurred with a zirconium crown?

Comment: Technology stories such as [this one](https://www.wired.com/2002/06/excuse-me-is-your-tooth-ringing/) aside, I have not found anything about dental implants resonating to the point where noises can be heard. Are you sure the patient's molar is resonating and the noises cannot be attributed to [tinnitus](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/tinnitus/)?

Comment: Yes this is a vibration phenomenon, characterized as vibration as opposed to sound.